# How to build a correct datagramPacket with header in android?

Tags: android, byte, packet, datagram

I have a packet that after de-serializing it (I saw it in the tests of the python example), looks like this:

```
header = Container: 
    pkt_type = PacketExample
    unprotected_payload_length = 19
    protected_payload_length = None
    version = 0
unprotected_payload = Container: 
    someid = u'FF00112233445566' (total 16)
protected_payload = None
```

now, the serialized packet looks like this (again from a python example):

```
b'\xdd\x02\x00\x13\x00\x00\x00\x10FF00112233445566\x00'
```

and this is the description of the message, of how the packet should look like:

```
Header
Offset (hex)    Offset (dec)    Type        Description
0x00               0              uint16      Packet Type
0x02               2              uint16      Unprotected Payload Length
0x04               4              uint16      *Protected Payload Length
0x08               8              uint16      Version

PacketExample value: 0xDD02

Unprotected payload:
Offset (hex)    Offset (dec)    Type    Description
0x00              0             String    Some ID
```

Now my question is, how should I create a DatagramPacket from those details with this kind of example?
If I would like to create the PacketExample I should do it like so?

```
String someId = "FF00112233445566";
String version = "0";
String protected_packet = "";
String packetAsString = "DD02" + someId.length() + protected_packet.length() + version + someId;
DatagramPacket datagram = new DatagramPacket(packetAsString.toByteArray(), 0, packetAsString.length);
```

because this doesn't works for me, and I don't get the same packet as in the example (`b'\xdd\x02\x00\x13\x00\x00\x00\x10FF00112233445566\x00'`)

Comment: You should use `DataInput/OutputStream` in conjunction with `ByteArrayInput/OutputStream` to parse/build the data. Not `String`.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne but does the way the raw string is built, is it correct? can u please ad an example of what u mean?

Comment: No, it isn't correct, because you shouldn't be using `String`, as I already stated. Have you considered consulting the Javadoc for the classes I mentioned?

Comment: @MarquisofLorne I have red it, but i can't see how it all fits together. `DataInput` doesn't create a packet, it just reads an incoming steam as far as I can tell.